# iterate over list of dictionaries within with_nested list

Tags: ansible

I have the following with_nested:

```
- name: Create solr schema for solr_cores
  uri:
    url: http://{{ cassandra_cluster_ips.split(',') | random }}:8983/solr/admin/cores?action={{ solr_core_action }}&core={{ item[1] }}.{{ item[0] }}
    timeout: "{{ solr_create_timeout }}"
  sudo: True

  with_nested:
     -  "{{ solr_cores }}"
 -  "{{ client_names }}"
```

I want to change to my extra vars from:

```
#solr_cores: ['dom_chunk_meta', 'dom', 'tra_chunk_meta','tra','dom_difference_results','me_output']
 #solr_core_action: "reload"
```

to:
    solr_cores: [{‘dom_difference_results’:‘create’}, {‘dom’:‘reload’}, 
    {‘tra’:‘reload’}, {‘me_output’:‘reload’}]

I looked at subelements, but don’t know how to pass it as a simple dictionary list so that I can set them into uri up to access it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure what you are trying to do but with_dict might be the one to use. If this doesn't work for you, comment and I will adjust the answer.

In your vars/inventory:

```
solr:
  - name: core1
    create_timeout: 30
    action: reload
  - name: core2
    action: create
    create_timeout: 60
```

In your playbook:

```
- name: Create solr schema for solr_cores
  uri:
    url: http://{{ cassandra_cluster_ips.split(',') | random }}:8983/solr/admin/cores?action={{ item.value.core_action }}&core={{ item.value.name }}.{{ item.value.other }}
    timeout: "{{ item.value.create_timeout }}"
  sudo: True
  with_dict: "{{ solr }}"
```

Comment: Are you sure this code works? solr is a list of dictionaries so I think with_dict doesn't work on solr.